URL_Launcher not launching URL in Flutter
I need my container to launch a URL whenever it is clicked. I have done this plenty times with other projects, yet it will not work in this current project. I believe I have added everything I need to the pubspec.yaml, AndroidManifest.xml, and Info.plist files. I have imported it in my main.dart, and when I run the app, nothing happens, as in, the container, when tapped, doesn't launch any URL. Have I forgotten to do something? Any help is appreciated.
Code:
InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              splashColor: Colors.transparent,
              highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    color: Colors.yellow.shade800,
                  ),
                  // color: Colors.yellow.shade800,
                  height: 60.0,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 100.0),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => launchUrl(Uri.parse(
                            'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sRc-uB6IgS4&list=PLNJd3WyRswnfgMo0sf8&index=1')),
                        child: const Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'Help',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

AndroidManifest.xml file:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Provide required visibility configuration for API level 30 and above -->
    <queries>
        <!-- If your app checks for SMS support -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your app checks for call support -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your application checks for inAppBrowserView launch mode support -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
    <application
        android:label="PocketAlgs"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>

And finally, my Info.plist file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>sms</string>
      <string>tel</string>
    </array>
        <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
        <true/>
        <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
        <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
        <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
        <string>PocketAlgs</string>
        <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
        <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
        <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
        <string>6.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleName</key>
        <string>testing_stuff_ignore</string>
        <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
        <string>APPL</string>
        <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
        <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
        <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
        <string>????</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
        <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
        <true/>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents</key>
        <true/>
        <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
        <string>LaunchScreen</string>
        <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
        <string>Main</string>
        <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
        <array>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</plist>


You are using InkWell widget as the parent of your Container, and you've placed the GestureDetector inside the Container. However, the GestureDetector won't receive tap events because InkWell captures them.
Instead, you can directly use GestureDetector.
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () => launchUrl(Uri.parse(
      'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sRc-uB6IgS4&list=PLNJd3WyRswnfgMo0sf8&index=1')),
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        color: Colors.yellow.shade800,
      ),
      height: 60.0,
      child: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 100.0),
          child: const Text(
            'Help',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),


Fixed: I forgot to restart my simulator. I restarted it, and now the URL is being launched.
